# Is a social security number required for a passport for an adult?

Tags: us-citizens, passport, social-security

I was born in the USA and at the age of 2 I moved to Mexico City where I lived here all my life.

Now I want to have my US citizen passport but don't have the SSN. 
Do I need to get this Social security number first before filling the DS-11 form?

Is there a chance I can get the passport without this number explaining or giving some documents that all my life I have been living outside the US?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Luis

Comment: Are you certain that you've never been issued a social security number?  At some point in the late 1980s or early 1990s it became routine for newborns to apply in the hospital.  If you were born after that, you may already have a number.  If you do, you should find out what it is.

Comment: How have you been filing US tax returns each year on your worldwide income without a SSN?

Answer (score 3):

According to the instructions for [Form DS-11 (U.S. Passport Application)](https://eforms.state.gov/Forms/ds11.pdf):

> Section 6039E of the Internal Revenue Code (26 U.S.C. 6039E) and 22 U.S.C 2714a(f) require you to provide your Social Security number (SSN), if you have one, when you apply for or renew a U.S. passport.  If you have never been issued a SSN, you must enter zeros in box #5 of this form.  If you  are  residing  abroad,  you  must  also  provide  the  name  of  the  foreign  country  in  which  you  are  residing.    The  U.S.  Department  of  State  must provide your SSN and foreign residence information to the U.S. Department of the Treasury.  If you fail to provide the information, your application may be denied and you are subject to a $500 penalty enforced by the IRS.  All questions on this matter should be referred to the nearest IRS office.

Other sections of the instructions say that if you fail to provide your social security number, then your application "MAY RESULT IN SIGNIFICANT PROCESSING DELAYS AND/OR THE DENIAL OF YOUR APPLICATION". However, if you are sure that you have *never* had an SSN, then the above instructions to fill in zeros apply.

Comment: To make this answer complete, a reference of the sorce of @phoog (applied **for** newborns in the hospitals) should be added.